# REGEX for finding author-year citations

Tags: regex

I need to design a complex REGEX-pattern, but i've made no significant progress in quite some time:

Basically I want to extract author-year citations from a text. I extracted the references out of text in brackets using REGEX

```
\(\K[^\)]+
```

There are several cases and variations to get the authors:

```
Simple: Smith, 2000 or Smith 2000
Multiple authors: Smith/Miller 2001 or Smith & Miller, 2001
Authors with hyphens: Smith-Miller, 2001, Max-Planck-Society, 2001
Authors with accents: O'Neill 2001
Organizations with all caps: ACME Company
And permutations of the above cases
```

Since I only keep text inside brackets, most of the false positives are eliminated, however some special cases exist:

- et al./etal./u.a./u. a. need to be kept
- there should be a year after the names ([0=9]{4})
- sometimes there are commas after the last name (Miller/Smith, 2001)
- it needs to support international characters

The easiest approach was this:

```
\b[\p{Lu}\/].*?[0-9]{4}\b
```

But it proved to greedy resulting in lots of not needed text.

So far my best approach is this:

```
(([\p{Lu}]+[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\-\' ]*)+)([\/](?1))*([ ](et[ ]{0,1}al\.)|(u\.[ ]{0,1}a\.)){0,1}[,]*([ ][0-9]{4})
```

But it has some problems:

- It recognizes multiple persons only when there is a ccomma (,)
- So Smith/Miller 2001 is not recognized, but Smith/Miller, 2001 is ok.

Is there a simple working solution? Like: Get everything, that

- does not start with lowercase
- can contain [\'/ ]
- is followed by 4 digits: [0-9]{4}
- can contain "et. al." before the digits
- can be separated by /

I tried to test the regex and its use cases here: https://regex101.com/r/HEA0rg/8

Comment: Are you sure this is a context free grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a repeating pattern where the divider is a space or forward slash to match words that start with an uppercase char and make the `et al.` part optional.

If `\h` is supported you could use it to match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars instead of a space.

```
\p{Lu}[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}'-]*(?:[ \/]\p{Lu}[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}'-]*)*(?: et al\.)?,? [0-9]{4}
```

**Pattern parts**

- `\p{Lu}` Match uppercase char
- `[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}'-]*` Match repeating 0+ times what is in the character class
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[ \/]\p{Lu}` Match space or `/`, start match with an uppercase char a
  - `[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}'-]*` Match any of the listed 0+ times
- `)*`  Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?: et al\.)?` Optionally match et al.
- `,? [0-9]{4}` Match optional comma and space, then match 4 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJM88g/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works as intended. Is there any reason for using a non-capturing group in `(?:[ \/]\p{Lu}[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}'-]*)` ?

Comment: The non capturing group repeats what is accepted in the character class preceded by `[ \/]` which will match a space or `/` so you can not have multiple spaces or `//`